# Charles proxy session export to test

Tags: jmeter, jmx, charles-proxy, gatling

I'm intercepting traffic of my mobile app using charles proxy. I've saved the session as a .chls file. Is there any way to convert this chls into a file which can be readed by jmeter or some other test application?
It would be great if I can build a test case using intercepted data.

And is there some way to export a Postman file to jmeter or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JMeter to capture your mobile traffic. Just

1. Switch your mobile device to use WiFi connection rather than cellular data
2. Make sure that your workstation running JMeter and mobile device are under the same subnet
3. Configure you mobile device to user JMeter's proxy (IP address of your machine and

   - either port 8080 if you use standalone [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
   - or port 8888 if you're using Recording template from File -> Templates menu

For more information and step-by-step configuration instructions see [Load Testing Mobile Apps. But Made Easy.](http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) guide

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use Charles Proxy, you can export into HAR format instead. You can then reimport into Gatling with the recorder in [HAR mode](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.2/http/recorder.html#har-files). Just beware that you might see some additional CONNECT requests over HTTPS, as Charles records traffic from its own standpoint: a proxy.

You can also export in HAR format from tools such as Google Chrome Dev Tool, without this CONNECT requests shortcoming.

Then, you can also use the Recorder in standard proxy mode.